# Authguard angularfire2 check if email verified

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I currently have the following code in my authguard to prevent routes from being visited when not logged in, but I would also like unverified users to be sent to a verify page, how would I do this?

```
canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
return Observable.from(this.auth)
  .take(1)
  .map(state => !!state)
  .do(authenticated => {
    if (!authenticated) this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check the value of the `emailVerified` property:

```ts
constructor(private af: AngularFire) { }

canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.af.auth
    .take(1)
    .map(auth => auth.auth.emailVerified)
    .do(emailVerified => {
      if (!emailVerified) this.router.navigate(['/verify-email']);
    });
}
```

Note. `this.auth` in your code is probably already an observable. No need to wrap it inside `Observable.from()`.

Comment: I just tried what you said here. I got: 

error_handler.js:56 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'auth' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'auth' of null

Comment: If `auth` is null, it probably means your current user is not authenticated, therefore you can't access its properties. You can fix it by testing in the code that `auth` is not null before trying to access `auth.auth.emailVerified`.